# Creating contours within an upper limited boundary

Tags: qgis, contour

I'm trying to create a series of contours for a dam site at 1m intervals below the full supply level. I created the supply area by extracting a specific contour line and cutting it off at the nominal location of the dam wall to create the surface area. Now I'd like to create polygons for progressive 1m reductions in the storage height (i.e. the surface area that the dam will contain when it falls in 1m increments).

I found the Hypsometric curve tool which will generate a CSV file that calculates the surface area of progressive 1m (or whatever interval you select) reductions in height of the storage, but I'm hoping I can find a tool that will generate a polygon for each progressive 1m reduction in height.

[image]

Comment: You can set the contour boundaries with [r.contour](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/r.contour.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the GDAL `Contour Polygons` from the processing toolbox:

[image]

Contour polygons:

[image]

This will generate polygons at the desired interval

Then use the Processing Toolbox `Intersection` tool with your lake surface polygon:
[image]

[image]

You get individual polygons with their elevation boundaries as attributes.

Comment: Or maybe the other way round? First, clip the dem to the extent of the lake (clip raster by mask layer), then create the contour polygons. Helps to save processing power as you only create contour polygons where you actually need them.

Comment: That's perfect - thanks so much for providing a worked example Kasper.

Comment: @PeterMac [What should I dont when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)